# How to filter by an specific attribute in an object in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have object in AngularJS:

```
 genres = [{
    label: "Trance",
    genre: "8",
    position: 8
}, {
    label: "House",  
    genre: "2",
    position: 8
}]
```

How to filter this array by `genre` by `ng-click`?
For example `ng-click="filterByGenre(2)"`.

It should returns me only one element:

```
{
    label: "House",  
    genre: "2",
    position: 8
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1rz9223/5/) of what your try to achieve. It does filter your object by attribute `genre` where you can search for the `Id` in the text field. For example `8`.

Take a look at the filter declaration `filter:{genre:searchGenre}` which holds the attribute name `genre` to filter and the model input `searchGenre`. For more information please take a look at the [AngularJS Documentation of filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

---

### The following example shows how to filter in View - [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y1rz9223/5/)

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Filter items</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchGenre">
    <h2>Genres</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="genre in genres | filter:{genre:searchGenre}">
      {{genre.label}}
    </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS app

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.genres = [{
      label: "Trance",
      genre: "8",
      position: 8
  }, {
      label: "House",  
      genre: "2",
      position: 8
  }];
}
```

---

### The following example shows how to filter in an controller - [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2xscufx6/1/)

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>Filter items</div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchGenre">
    <div>Genres</div>
    <div ng-repeat="genre in filtered">
      {{genre.label}}
    </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS App

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {

   $scope.genres = [{
      label: "Trance",
      genre: "8",
      position: 8
  }, {
      label: "House",  
      genre: "2",
      position: 8
  }];

  //init search phrase
  $scope.searchGenre = '';

  //init filtered scope
  $scope.filtered = [];

  /**
   * Watch keyword change
   */
  $scope.$watch('searchGenre', function(term) {
    $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.genres, {'genre': term});
  });
}
```

Comment: Whats `filterFilter`?

Comment: Filters can be injected as a service. Whose name is `<nameOfTheFilter>Filter`

Comment: But I dont see filter in your example as service

Comment: Its an AngularJS core service. Here is a list of core filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/. My example is using `filter`.

Comment: It does not work `filterFilter` when I inject this in controller

Comment: It does work, like it works in my fiddle. Maybe your injection syntax is wrong.

Comment: I use AJ 1.5 ,,

Comment: The example is using AngularJS 1.0.1. Your injection syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.genres = [
                {
                    label: "Trance",
                    genre: "8",
                    position: 8
                },

                {
                    label: "House",  
                    genre: "2",
                    position: 8
                }
  ];
          
          $scope.setGenreFilter = function(genre){
           $scope.genreFilter = genre; 
          }
          
          
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>Filter items</div>
    <span ng-repeat="genre in genres" ng-click="setGenreFilter(genre.genre)">{{genre.genre}}, </span>
    <div>****************GENRE**********************</div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in genres | filter:{genre:genreFilter}">
      {{item.label}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function

```js
genres.filter(function(item){
  return item.genre == '2';
});
```

or you can do it the old for loop way

```js
var filteredData = [];
for(var i=0;i<genres.length;i++){
  if(genres[i].genre == '2'){
    filteredData.push(genres[i]);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Just replace the '2' with a variable. I added '2' just for instance.

Comment: How this answer refers to angular scope?

Comment: It does not need to I guess. If you read the question, it says - How to filter this array by genre by ng-click? For example ng-click="filterByGenre(2)". What I have given is the body of the function `filterByGenre`